# C# Combine String from Json Webrequest before binding Windows Universal

Tags: c#, json, binding, listbox

I got a Listbox with a data template which is containing an image. The source of the image should be a combinition of a static url (etc. http://www.google.de/) and a String value I get from a Json webrequest which is in a list in the rootobject in the jsonclass.
So I have in my Jsonclass the String value:

```
  public string icon_url { get; set; }
```

And before I can bind to this I need to combine for each item the static uri and the individual icon_url. How do i do this? And no I cant use multiple bindings in xaml it's not supported in windows universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting the ItemsSource to your list box you could do the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
   myList[i].icon_url = "my_base_url" + myList[i].icon_url;
```

After that just set the ItemSource